# Pass variable from PHP to jQuery click() function

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

Can some one tell me how to pass variable `Y`to `$('a:eq(0)').click()`? I need to alert the server respond to the `.click()` function. I am using a PHP framework if that's important.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        function clockIn(str){
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
            { // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
            }
            else
            {// code for IE6, IE5
                xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }

            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
            {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
                {
                    document.getElementById("message").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
                    var y = xmlhttp.responseText ; 

                }
            }
            xmlhttp.open("GET","http://localhost/gasstation/index.php/welcome/check_time_clock/"+ str,true);
            xmlhttp.send();
        } 

        $( "input:submit, a", ".login" ).button();

        $("a:eq(0)").click(function(){
            clockIn(<?php echo $emp_id; ?>);
        });

        $("a:eq(1)").click(function(){
            alert('m') ;
        })
    });
</script>
```

Comment: could you be more precise as what are you trying to achieve..?

Comment: If you're trying to alert the server you could use GET or POST and ajax with a URL to a php page that reads these in and then does something server side.

Comment: Since you've jQuery in your code, you could have used jQuery ajax, that would be lot more easier

Comment: i dont want to use the jquery .ajax() since iam still learning

Comment: i think the call back function is what i missed

Comment: i dont get any errors ... the problem was that i just can't get the Y value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are making an ajax call you have to wait until the server responds so you cannot get the value of `y` inside `click` hanlder. You can pass a handler to `clockIn` and then execute it once the ajax response comes. Try this.

```
function clockIn(str, callback){
   ...
   xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
   {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
      {
        document.getElementById("message").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        var y = xmlhttp.responseText ; 
        callback(y);
      }
   }
   ...
}


$("a:eq(0)").click(function(){
   clockIn("<?php echo $emp_id; ?>", function(y){
      //You will get the value of y here.
      alert(y);
   });
});
```

Since you are using jQuery you should leverage it completly to make your code simple and clean. Instead of creating write the code your own to create `xmlhttp` request object and bla bla you can smply use `$.ajax` of jQuery for the same use. Your code will become like this.

```
function clockIn(str, callback){
   $.ajax({
      url: "http://localhost/gasstation/index.php/welcome/check_time_clock/"+ str,
      success: function(data){
         $("#message").html(data);
         callback(data);
      }
   });
}
```

Comment: it works fine but i still not understand what you did will you explain it more please " the first code "

Comment: I added one more paramater to `clockIn` function as callback. When you click on `a` it will call `clockIn` function passing the emp_id and the callback function. When `clockIn` function makes ajax call and response comes, we just call the callback function passing the response from server.

Comment: @MinaGabriel - Mark this as an answer if this worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("a:eq(0)").click(function(){
        clockIn('<?php echo $emp_id; ?>');

    });
```

May Be it will Help

Answer (score 0):

```
function clockIn(str, cb) {
    $.get("http://localhost/gasstation/index.php/welcome/check_time_clock/"+ str), function(res) {
        // do your stuffs here.
        var y = res;
        cb && cb(y);
    }
}

$("a:eq(0)").click(function(){
    clockIn("hello", function(y){ alert(y); }); // your y here
});
```

Comment: can you tell me exactely what did you do

Comment: `$.get(url, callback)` is jQuery shortcut for the 10 lines+ of your xmlhttp object (since you use `$('a:eq(0)')` that's mean you already have jQuery anyway so why don't just use it.

`cb && cb(y);` is a way to pass your y value to `.click` when your ajax completed.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this since your using jQuery:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var clockIn = function (str) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost/gasstation/index.php/welcome/check_time_clock/"+ str,
            success: function (data) {
                $("#message").html(data);
                var y = data;
            }
        });
    }

    $( "input:submit, a", ".login" ).button();

    $("a:eq(0)").click(function(){
        clockIn('<?php echo $emp_id; ?>');
    });
    $("a:eq(1)").click(function(){
        alert('m') ;
    });

});
</script>
```

I hope this helps you out